# What happens to a blocked caller?

Tags: messages, ios, facetime, call

So I can block callers from iOS 7 now (Settings > Messages > Blocked) and I'm told it blocks voice, iMessages, and FaceTime. What happens when they try to contact me? Are they told the number is disconnected or do they get some kind of recording? If they call, does it ring indefinitely? Same for FaceTime? Do their texts bounce back or are they sent thought I never see them?

Comment: No, the caller doesn't get a notice. True call blocking has to come at the carrier level. If it's on the device (like in iOS 7), then the call will just ring indefinitely until the caller hangs up or until voice mail catches it (they can still leave a message). Essentially, iOS just cuts the ringtone and any notifications that come with the call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As someone posted in your question, it's not true call blocking in that the call still connects to your service but the phone silently rejects it without any indication to you. Since it still hits your voicemail, it's not really blocked, just not answered (more like `Do Not Disturb`)

I just tried this with my wife's phone. When she called, she initially hears a single ring but then it is immediately bumped to voicemail.

As I mentioned you aren't made aware of this, and to the caller it just appears that you've instantly declined the call.

With regards to SMSs, you can still send them SMSs and they can even see when you're typing the message, however, you won't see them typing, nor will you receive any texts from them. On iMessage, it actually appears to them that you have received the message.