# Can I block only the Facetime calls from a specific person, not calls or texts?

Tags: facetime

I want to block Facetime calls from a specific person, but not phone calls or texts. How can I do that?

Comment: Also see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102846/what-happens-to-a-blocked-caller

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Unfortunately, you can only block them from all three or none at all. This may change with future iOS updates, but for now, there is no way.